# Datepicker only the calendar should be visible

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, calendar

Under JavaFX there is the date picker. Unfortunately, this DatePicker has an input field / search bar (see the first photo).
I do not need this search bar, so I'd like to remove this. Only the calendar should be visible (see the second picture)

Thank you in advance, I am grateful for help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You cant access the private CalendarView class if thats what you are asking. If you want to just hind the TextField and only have the Button which makes the calendar view to appear, then thats possible to do by setting a small value to the width of the DatePicker. In any case I suggest to create one calendar from scratch or use an existed 3rd party library.

Comment: You could also look at the HTML5 datepicker attribute to see if that suites your needs.  <input id="date" type="date">

Comment: Search `ControlsFX` extras